# Como determinar quais tipos de caracteres poderão entrar no input?

Tags: html, regex, input

Tenho um formulário de Login e tenho que limitar o `input` a receber caracteres com as seguintes condições:

- Uma letra maiúscula
- Um número
- Um caracter Especial
- Um mínimo de 8 caracteres
- Caracteres especiais só podem ser esses: `@#$` (Mais importante)

**OBS**: Já fiz os filtros no arquivo PHP, que recebe esses dados do `form` de login, porém gostaria de fazer isso também diretamente nos `inputs` para garantir.

Sempre me complico quando tento usar `pattern`. Se vocês puderem me dar uma solução prática, eu agradeço.

Seguem abaixo o código dos meus dois botões de login:

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="formulario-login-sistema">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="login">Usuário:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="login" name="login" placeholder="Usuário" required autofocus />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="password" id="senha" min="10" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required />
  </div>


  <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Se der pra fazer sem JavaScript, melhor ainda.

Quase consegui utilizando o código abaixo:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" pattern="(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W+)(?=^.{8,50}$).*$" required />
```

Porém, ai está liberando todos os caracteres especiais e eu só gostaria de liberar esses 3: `@#$`.

Comment: Eu quase consegui utilizando assim: <input class="form-control" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" pattern="(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*\W+)(?=^.{8,50}$).*$" required />. Porém dessa forma ele possibilita a entrada de qualquer caractere especial. E eu só gostaria de permitir os caracteres especiais (@#$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/377918/112052) chegou perto. Mas [segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password#pattern), a expressão regular usada no atributo `pattern` deve ser uma regex válida no JavaScript. Então fiz um teste com a sua regex:

```js
let r = /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@-#-$])(?=^.{8,50}$).*$/;
```

Testei o código acima no Chrome, e deu esse erro:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@-#-$])(?=^.{8,50}$).*$/:
Range out of order in character class
```

Ou seja, a regex é inválida. O problema é que a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/password#pattern) diz que, caso a regex seja inválida, o atributo `pattern` é ignorado. Por isso, ao usá-la no HTML, o erro passa despercebido.

O problema está no trecho que verifica os caracteres especiais: os hífens em `[@-#-$]` causam o erro. Dentro de colchetes, os hífens possuem significado especial, pois servem para definir um intervalo (como `[a-z]`, que define um intervalo de `a` a `z`).

Só que os intervalos [aceitam quaisquer caracteres](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-interesting-character-classes.html), então a regex interpreta o trecho `@-#` como o intervalo entre os caracteres `@` e `#`. E se você olhar na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/), verá que o `#` vem antes do `@`, então o intervalo é inválido (é o que a mensagem de erro informa: "Range out of order"). É como se eu tentasse usar `[z-a]`, que é inválido pois o `a` vem antes do `z` na tabela ASCII ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/sRK38Z/1/)).

Então a primeira coisa a fazer é remover esses hífens e deixar apenas os caracteres que você quer verificar.

Em seguida, eu também recomendo colocar o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` no início da expressão. Isso é melhor por causa dos [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (os trechos que começam com `(?=`), já que eles verificam se algo existe e depois voltam para onde estava. Usando `^` antes deles, eu garanto que a busca pelos caracteres sempre ocorre no início da string.

Sem o `^`, a regex pode repetir as buscas várias vezes (primeiro começando no início da string, depois começando a partir do segundo caractere, e assim por diante). Isso é um problema para strings inválidas, pois a regex demora mais para perceber que ela é inválida: [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/pT4cjz/2/debugger) que sem o `^` ela leva mais de 160 passos para perceber que a string é inválida. Já usando `^` ela [leva apenas 34 passos](https://regex101.com/r/AqrxCo/3/debugger) - a quantidade exata de passos pode variar de acordo com o tamanho da string, e claro que para strings pequenas não terá tanta diferença de desempenho, mas de qualquer forma é uma otimização simples e eu prefiro fazê-la. Além disso, o uso do `^`, juntamente com o `$` (que significa o final da string), também garante que a string só terá o que está na regex.

Outro detalhe é o `.{8,50}` (entre 8 e 50 caracteres). O ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere, então sua senha poderá ser, por exemplo, `Abc123@!` ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/b7kehB/1/)). Repare que ela possui o caractere `!`, e isso é perfeitamente válido, já que o *lookahead* `(?=.*[@#$])` só obriga que exista pelo menos um dentre `@#$`, mas o ponto aceita quaisquer outros caracteres (por isso `.{8,50}` também aceita o `!`).

Se você quiser que a senha tenha somente letras, números e `@#$`, basta mudar a regex para:

```css
/* deixa uma borda vermelha enquanto o campo estiver inválido */
input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
  <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha"
   pattern="^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@#$])[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]{8,50}$" required />
</form>
```

No início temos `^` (início da string), e em seguida temos os *lookaheads*, cada um verificando se existe determinado tipo de caractere (letra maiúscula, minúscula, dígitos ou um dos caracteres `@#$`). Cada *lookahead* verifica se um tipo de caractere existe e volta para onde estava (no caso, o início da string), e em seguida continua avaliando o restante da expressão.

Em vez do ponto, eu uso `[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]`, o que faz com que a regex não aceite mais `!` (nem qualquer outro caractere que não esteja entre os colchetes). Agora ela só aceita o que está nessa lista: letras, números ou `@#$`. E o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{8,50}` indica a quantidade mínima (8) e máxima (50) desses caracteres.

Lembrando que o `[a-zA-Z0-9@#$]` sozinho não obriga que tenha pelo menos uma letra maiúscula, uma minúscula, um número e um caractere especial. Ela só obriga que os caracteres sejam qualquer um desta lista, então se eu usasse somente isso e a senha só tivesse várias letras `A`, ela seria válida ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/AvIgvn/1/)). Para obrigar que cada tipo de caractere exista (letras, números, etc), ainda são necessários os *lookaheads*.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que consegui utilizando o seguinte código:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="senha">Senha:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" pattern="(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[@-#-$])(?=^.{8,50}$).*$" required />
</div>
```

Nesse caso, o campo deverá ter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula, uma minúscula, um número e um caractere especial que seja um desses três (@#$). E também deverá ter um mínimo de 8 e o máximo de 50 caracteres.

Se alguém tiver alguma ressalva ou algo a acrescentar, é só comentar.

Comment: O problema é que o ponto aceita qualquer coisa, então `.*` aceita outros caracteres especiais além de `@#$`. Tem outras coisas pra arrumar também, dê uma olhada na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/378901/112052) para mais detalhes :-)

Answer (score 0):

Para limitar exemplo:  `Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10"><br>`
Para caracteriais especiais tenta esse: `pattern="[@-#]+"`

Comment: entendi sua colocação. Mas o que eu desejaria era que atendesse aquelas especificações que eu citei. Não que eu queira pronto o código. Porém eu gostaria de saber como eu aplico aquelas condições dentro de um pattern.

Answer (score -3):

```react
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { faCheck, faTimes, faInfoCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import axios from './api/axios'

const USER_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,23}$/;
const PWD_REGEX = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%]).{8,24}$/;
const REGISTER_URL = '/register'

const Register = () => {
    const userRef = useRef();
    const errRef = useRef();

    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [validName, setValidName] = useState(false);
    const [userFocus, setUserFocus] = useState(false);
    
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const [validPwd, setValidPwd] = useState(false);
    const [pwdFocus, setPwdFocus] = useState(false);
    
    const [matchPwd, setMatchPwd] = useState('');
    const [validMatch, setValidMatch] = useState(false);
    const [matchFocus, setMatchFocus] = useState(false);
    
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');
    const [success, setSuccess] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        userRef.current.focus();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        const result = USER_REGEX.test(user);
        console.log(result);
        console.log(user);
        setValidName(result);
        
    }, [user])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const result = PWD_REGEX.test(pwd);
        console.log(result);
        console.log(pwd);
        setValidPwd(result);
        const match = pwd === matchPwd;
        setValidMatch(match)    
    }, [pwd, matchPwd])

    useEffect(() => {
        setErrMsg('');
    },[user, pwd, matchPwd])

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        const v1 = USER_REGEX.test(user)
        const v2 = PWD_REGEX.test(pwd)
        if(!v1 || !v2) {
            setErrMsg('´Caracter invalido');
            return
        }
        /*
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                REGISTER_URL,
                JSON.stringify({ user, pwd }),
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    withCredentials: true
                })
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.accessToken);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
                setSuccess(true)
                //clear input
                    
        } catch(err) {
            if(!err?.response) {
                setErrMsg('Servidor sem resposta')
            } else if(err.response?.status === 409) {
                setErrMsg('Usuário já cadastrado')
            } else {
                setErrMsg('Falha no resgistro')
            }
            errRef.current.focus()    
        }*/
    }


    return (
        <>
        {success ? (
            <section>
                <h1>Cadastro confirmado!</h1>
                <p>
                    <a href="/">Entre na conta</a>
                </p>
            </section>
        ) : (
        <section>
            <p ref={errRef} className={ errMsg ? "errmsg" : "offscreen" } aria-live="assertive">{errMsg}</p>
            <h1>Registro</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="username">
                    Usuário:
                    <span className={validPwd ? "valid" : "hide"}> 
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                    </span>
                    <span className={validPwd || !user ? "hide" : "invalid"}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="username"
                    ref={userRef}
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    aria-invalid={validPwd ? "false" : "true"}
                    aria-describedby="uidnote"
                    onFocus={() => setUserFocus(true)}
                    onBlur={() => setUserFocus(false)}
                />    
                <p id="uidnote" className={userFocus && user && !validPwd ? "instructions" : "offscreen"}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />
                    4 de 24 characters.<br/>
                    Precisa começar com uma letra.<br />
                    Letras, números, underlines, hifens são aceitos 
                </p>
                <label htmlFor="password">
                    Senha:
                    <span className={validPwd ? "valid" : "hide"}> 
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                    </span>
                    <span className={validPwd || !pwd ? "hide" : "invalid"}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={(e) => setPwd(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    aria-invalid={validPwd ? "false" : "true"}
                    aria-describedby="pwdnote"
                    onFocus={() => setPwdFocus(true)}
                    onBlur={() => setPwdFocus(false)}
                />    
                <p id="pwdnote" className={pwdFocus && pwd && !validPwd ? "instructions" : "offscreen"}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />
                    8 de 24 characters.<br/>
                    Precisa conter letras maiúsculas e minúsculas, números e caracter especial.<br />
                    São permitidos: <span aria-label="exclamation mark">!</span><span aria-label="at symbol">@</span><span aria-label="#hashtag">#</span>
                    <span aria-label="dollar sign">$</span><span aria-label="percent">%</span>    
                </p>
                <label htmlFor="confirm_pwd">
                    Confirme a senha:
                    <span className={validMatch && matchPwd ?  "valid" : "hide"}> 
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} />
                    </span>
                    <span className={validMatch || !matchPwd ? "hide" : "invalid"}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTimes} />
                    </span>
                </label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    id="confirm_pwd"
                    autoComplete="off"
                    onChange={(e) => setMatchPwd(e.target.value)}
                    required
                    aria-invalid={validMatch ? "false" : "true"}
                    aria-describedby="confirmenote"
                    onFocus={() => setMatchFocus(true)}
                    onBlur={() => setMatchFocus(false)}
                />  
                <p id="confirmnote" className={matchFocus && !validMatch ? "instructions" : "offscreen"}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faInfoCircle} />
                    Precisa ser igual a digitada acima.     
                </p>
                <button disabled={!validName || !validPwd || !validMatch ? true : false}>
                    Confirme
                </button>
            </form>
            <p>
                Já é registrado?<br />
                <span className="line">
                {/*link router*/}
                <a href="/">Faça login</a>    
                </span>

            </p>
        </section>
        )}
        </>
    )
}

export default Register
```

Comment: A pergunta se refere apenas a HTML e JavaScript puro.