# regex para senha

Tags: jquery, android, regex

gostaria de saber como posso fazer um regex que contenha no minimo 8 digitos sendo obrigatório 1 digito com @!# 1 digito em maiúsculo e um digito com numerais de 0 a 9

tentei algo com o https://regex101.com/ mas o máximo que consegui foi :

```
([0-9]{1}[!@#]{1}[a-zA-Z]){8,}
```

muito agradecido se conseguirem me ajudar :)

Comment: Já tem algo parecido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342605/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377860/112052)

Comment: Cara, valeu! consegui resolver o problema! @hkotsubo

Comment: Só uma obs.: não existe dígito maiúsculo. Existe "letra maiúscula". :D

Comment: sim, mas eu peguei o padrão e corrigi!

Comment: ficou dessa forma: ^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@!#])[a-zA-Z0-9@!#]{8,}$

Comment: Uma dica pra futuras regex que vc for usar: `{1}` não é necessário, pois `[0-9]{1}` é o mesmo que `[0-9]` - na verdade, `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`