# Validar campos de senha usando Javascript / Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou montando uma página onde o usuário poderá trocar a sua senha e preciso validar dois input's com as seguintes regras:

1. a senha precisa ter 1 caractere e 1 número.
2. não podem haver 2 caracteres ou números repetidos (Ex: "aa", "11")

Já consegui resolver o item 1 com Regex, mas não estou conseguindo resolver o item 2.

```js
    validador: function(){
     //this.form.senha && this.form.senha são os locais dos inputs

        if (this.form.senha_confirmacao != this.form.senha) {
            alert('As duas senhas estão divergentes')
            return false;
        } else {

            let senha = this.form.senha_confirmacao;
            let regex = /^(?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){0})(?=(?:.*?[0-9]){1})(?=(?:.*?[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]){0})(?!.*\s)[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%;*(){}_+^&]*$/; 

            if(senha.length < 6){                
                Notify.create({message: "A senha deve conter no minímo 6 digitos!"});            
                return false;

                } else if(!regex.exec(senha)){                    
                    Notify.create({message: "A senha deve conter no mínimo 1 número e 1 letra"});            
                    return false;

                }   
                    return true;  


    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua regex está meio confusa. Por exemplo, é usado o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{0}`, que significa "zero ocorrências". Ou seja, você definiu um trecho que não ocorre (ou que "ocorre zero vezes", que é o mesmo que "não existir") e por isso ele é ignorado. Tanto que o trecho `(?:.*?[A-Z]){0}` não está obrigando a ter letras, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/vTCoLD/1/).

Também há o uso de `{1}`, que quer dizer "uma ocorrência". Mas por padrão, qualquer coisa que você coloque em uma regex já significa que aquilo ocorrerá uma vez, então ele é redundante e pode ser removido (`(alguma coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(alguma coisa)`).

Então para verificar se a senha deve obrigatoriamente ter uma letra e um número, basta trocar os [*lookaheads*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) para `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` e `(?=.*[0-9])` (repare que usei `[a-zA-Z]`, pois `[A-Z]` só pega letras maiúsculas).

Pelo que entendi você também quer verificar a presença de pelo menos um dos caracteres especiais (`[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.]`), já que tem um *lookahead* para eles, então basta tirar o `{0}` dele também.

E se você quer validar o tamanho da string, pode fazer na própria regex: em vez de usar `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), pode usar `{6,}` (no mínimo 6 ocorrências, sem limite máximo). Se quiser limitar também o valor máximo, pode usar algo como `{6,20}` (no mínimo 6, no máximo 20 ocorrências).

O trecho `(?!.*\s)` também me parece desnecessário: ele verifica se não há espaços, TAB's ou quebras de linha (que é o que o [atalho `\s` significa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)), mas como o restante da regex já é bem restritivo quanto a isso, essa verificação é redundante e também pode ser removida.

---

Para verificar se o mesmo caractere se repete em posições consecutivas, você pode usar [parênteses para criar um grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) e em seguida usar [*backreferences*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) para se referir a este grupo. A ideia básica é fazer algo assim:

```
(caractere)(?!\1)
```

Os parênteses capturam o caractere, e `\1` contém o caractere que foi capturado. O *negative lookahead* `(?!\1)` verifica se esse caractere **não** ocorre logo depois. Ou seja, isso verifica se o mesmo caractere não ocorre duas vezes consecutivas (no caso, o "caractere" é o trecho que você quer verificar: `[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%;*(){}_+^&]`). Aí basta repetir essa estrutura várias vezes:

```
(?:(caractere)(?!\1)){6,}
```

Assim, eu tenho um caractere que não aparece duas vezes seguidas, e isso acontece no mínimo 6 vezes. A expressão completa fica:

```js
function valida(senha) {
    let regex = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%;*(){}_+^&])(?!\1)){6,}$/;
    if (regex.test(senha)) {
        console.log(senha, '= válida');
    } else {
        console.log(senha, '= inválida');
    }
}

['a@1', 'abc@123', 'aab@123'].forEach(s => valida(s));
```

<sup>*[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/gVPk9I/5/) a regex funcionando.*</sup>

---

A regex acima considera que os caracteres especiais também não podem se repetir (se tiver `@@`, a string é inválida). Mas se quiser evitar que somente as letras e números se repitam, basta mudar para:

```
/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%*()_+^&}{:;?.])(?:([0-9a-zA-Z])(?!\1)|[!@#$%;*(){}_+^&]){6,}$/
```

Agora a regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), e tem duas opções:

- `([0-9a-zA-Z])(?!\1)`: uma letra ou número, desde que não se repita
- `[!@#$%;*(){}_+^&]`: um dos caracteres especiais

Assim, `@@` é considerado válido, mas `aa` e `11` não. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/gVPk9I/6/) a regex funcionando.

---

Você pode ler mais sobre o uso de regex para validar senhas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342605/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377860/112052).

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente!

Eu ainda sou muito novo em relação a trabalhar com regex e afins. Onde vc acha que eu poderia estudar melhor o uso dele e me aperfeiçoar nessa linha de programação?

Comment: @lucasmenezes Dois sites que eu gosto bastante são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e [esse](https://www.rexegg.com). E livros, eu recomendo [esse](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432)