# Expressão Regular para Senha Segura

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de uma ajuda para conseguir incluir na expressão regular que estou utilizando para não permitir espaços.

A senha deve atender os seguintes requisitos:

- Possua pelo menos 1 número;
- Possua pelo menos 1 letra maiúscula;
- Possua pelo menos 1 letra minúscula;
- Possua pelo menos 1 caractere especial;
- Não permitir espaço

Estou utilizando a seguinte expressão:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_@#$%]).{8,}
```

Comment: Já tem algo parecido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/342605/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/337924/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377860/112052)

Answer (score 1):

Sua expressão parece boa, mas substitua o `=.` por `=.?*`.
Além disso, faltam caracteres especiais no último grupo, e não está na pergunta mas, está também limitando ao mínimo de 8 caracteres (último grupo da *expression*).

Pode ser algo como:

```js
$("input").keypress(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    var regex = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$");
    
    if(regex.test(input)) {
        $("#mensagem").hide();
    }else {
        $("#mensagem").show();
    }
});
```

```css
label {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<label id="mensagem">Inválido</label>
```

Comment: O único problema é que continua aceitando espaço

Comment: @AndréMachadodeVargas Aceita espaço porque no final tem `.{8,}` e o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (inclusive espaços). Se quer limitar o que pode ter, tem que ser mais específico, por exemplo: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[-_@#$%])[-\w@#$%]{8,}$`. Troquei o ponto por `[-\w@#$%]` (o `\w` é um atalho para letras, números e `_`), assim só poderá ter os caracteres que estão entre as chaves. [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/dV8BUY/1/) a regex funcionando.